# gmail API deleting eMails using service account

Tags: c#, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I am trying to read and delete my mails for some Automated tests, my problem is I cant use oauth because it requiers user input. So I was trying to use an service account

But when I ran my code I got this an Error

Now im wondering if there is anything wrong with my code or with my permissions in the Google console

**Error:**

> 'One or more errors occurred. (Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:"")'

Occured here: `credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result`

**Code**

```
        private ServiceAccountCredential credential;
        private GmailService Service { get; set; }

        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        private static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
        private static string applicationName = "EmailReader";
        private static string credentialsFile = "emailreader-289206-c91027110691.p12";
        private static string keyPassword = "notasecret";
        private static string serviceAccountEmail = "auristesterdienstkonto@emailreader-289206.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        private static string userEmail = "auristester1@gmail.com";

        private Func<Message, bool> lastFilter;

        public GmailLibary() //my constructor
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
                credentialsFile,
                keyPassword,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    User = userEmail,
                    Scopes = Scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate)
            );

            if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                Service = new GmailService(
                    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        ApplicationName = applicationName,
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

**Permissions**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."

Normally means that you are using the code for a service account, but you have not created service account credentials on Google cloud console.  Make sure that the service account you have set up also appears on [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)  I'm not sure that the service account created over on Google cloud platform is the same thing. (not that i have tested it.)

In the case of Gmail API it is also the result of you not having properly set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings?hl=en) in your google workspace account.   Remember that service accounts only work with the gmail api with one of your domain emails you cant use it with a standard gmail email.